# realizar update mediante cruce en 2 tablas

Tags: sqlite, update, sqlite3

tengo mi base de datos (mel) con 2 tablas contactos y tdo.

mi tabla contactos tiene 2 columnas (cta, sdo) y tabla tdo(cta,sdo) contienen mas columnas pero por el momento solo me interesan esas.

entonces deseo un update en sdo ="vacio" from contactos a, tdo b where a.cta = b.cta and a.sdo = b.sdo

lo cual en palabras simples seria que mi columna sdo en tabla contactos sea igual a vacio (literal), cuando a.cta=b.cta y a.sdo=b.sdo de ambas tablas sean iguales.

estoy utilizando sqlite

espero haberme dado a entender.

Answer (score 0):

Esto funcionara si comprendo lo que buscas:

```
UPDATE contactos a SET a.sdo = "" WHERE a.cta IN (SELECT a.cta 
                                                  FROM tdo b 
                                                  WHERE a.cta = b.cta AND a.sdo = b.sdo)
```

Tomando en cuenta que tienes estos datos de ejemplo

```
SELECT * FROM contactos a, tdo b WHERE a.cta = b.cta AND a.sdo = b.sdo
```

[image: select tablas]

Despues de ejecutar el update tendrias `SELECT * FROM contactos a, tdo b WHERE a.cta = b.cta`

[image: select tablas luego del update]

Comment: Este es el siguiente error que me muestra,  near "a": syntax error

Comment: puedes añadir mas informacion sobre el error al ejecutar el update?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "a": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE contactos a SET a.sdo = "" WHERE a.cta IN (SELECT a.cta FROM tdo b WHERE a.cta = b.cta AND a.sdo = b.sdo), es todo lo que me muestra

Comment: intenta cambiando las comillas dobles por comillas simples UPDATE contactos a SET a.sdo = '' WHERE a.cta IN (SELECT a.cta 
                                                  FROM tdo b 
                                                  WHERE a.cta = b.cta AND a.sdo = b.sdo);

Comment: Vengo de la estructura de Fox pro ejecutando SQL al parecer no funciona de la misma manera e visto que aveces en sql utilizan [nombrebase].[tabla]  [nombre_columna] a, aún no entiendo la estructura en sql

Comment: update [contactos] set phstcollid = "cambio" where phacct in (select phacct from [tdos] where phacct = cuenta and phphone = locacion).  Parece encontré la solución realize la operación y se ejecutó de manera correcta, solo utilice otras tablas para no afectar mis tablas de trabajo. Se agradece el aporte y ayuda.

Comment: You are welcome :)